# solr SolrCore java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character

Tags: solr

I am getting this error in solr. Can any one help?

> ERROR SolrCorejava.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed
>   character class near index 3 java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
>   Unclosed character class near index 3 at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)

Comment: post your code so that we can debug the issue

Comment: Exactly what does your regular expression look like? Unclosed character classes might be unescaped `-` or `[`, but can also be caused by other special characters that should be escaped.

Comment: I am getting this errors now in solr 
ERROR
SolrCore
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252.*
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:3104)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2101)